# Aggregate Operator

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Here I have the following XML Data:

```
<RepairOrderEvent>
    <EventType>Advisor - Repair Facility</EventType>
    <EventDateTime>2019-01-07T11:18:38.8756279-06:00</EventDateTime>
    <EventNotes>Weld-through primer is not included.; Rule Type: Estimate Line; Score: 1; Variance: 0.0; UniqueSequenceNum: 9</EventNotes>
</RepairOrderEvent>
<RepairOrderEvent>
    <EventType>Advisor - Shared Guidelines</EventType>
    <EventDateTime>2019-01-07T11:18:38.8756279-06:00</EventDateTime>    
    <EventNotes>FAF(Part):More cost effective approved Bumper Cover avail, SELECT or DOCUMENT CA; Score: 11; Variance: 402.14; UniqueSequenceNum: 2; Insurance Score: 250</EventNotes>
</RepairOrderEvent>
<RepairOrderEvent>
    <EventType>Advisor - Shared Guidelines</EventType>
    <EventDateTime>2019-01-07T11:18:38.8756279-06:00</EventDateTime>
    <EventNotes>FAF(Part):More cost effective approved Cert Headlamp avail, SELECT or DOC; Score: 11; Variance: 164.04; UniqueSequenceNum: 6; Insurance Score: 250</EventNotes>
</RepairOrderEvent>    
<RepairOrderEvent>
    <EventType>Advisor - Shared Guidelines</EventType>
    <EventDateTime>2019-01-07T11:18:38.8756279-06:00</EventDateTime>
    <EventNotes>FAF(Profile): LKQ Markup Exceeds Rate Guide; Score: 11; Variance: 24.8; UniqueSequenceNum: 0; Insurance Score: 10</EventNotes>
</RepairOrderEvent>
```

As you guys can see, there is both a score and insurance score. I am only interested in "score" as well as the number next to it.
I need to create an operator that gets the value of score and spits out an aggregate total of all the scores (insurance score is not included).

In terms of what to do, I have loaded the XML document and I am running into a wall when it comes to parsing through the data.The end goal here is to be able to read each line for the first occurrence, drop the remainder of the string and find the sum of the score.

Here is a bit of what I have so far:

```
case "Aggregate": 
{
    XmlDocument currentWorkfileDoc = new XmlDocument();
    currentWorkfileDoc.LoadXml(currentWorkfileXML);

    foreach (XmlNode row in currentWorkfileDoc.SelectNodes("EventNotes"))
    {
        var rowName = row.SelectNodes("EventNote"); 
    }

    if (result)
        return result;
}
break;
```

Comment: If you use `XDocument` instead you can do this much easier with Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use `XDocument` then you can do something like:

```
var currentWorkfileDoc = XDocument.Load(memoConfigFile);
var sum = (from item in currentWorkfileDoc.Elements("EventNotes")
            select Regex.Split(item.Value, @"\D+")[0]).Sum(x => int.Parse(x));
```

or try below code with `XmlDocument` as you want:

```
XmlDocument currentWorkfileDoc = new XmlDocument();
currentWorkfileDoc.LoadXml(currentWorkfileXML); 
int sum = 0;
XmlNodeList elemList = currentWorkfileDoc.GetElementsByTagName("EventNotes");
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
    sum += int.Parse(Regex.Split(elemList[i].Value, @"\D+")[0]);
```

**Update:**

I tried that `Regex` will find all number as string array but the first index of array is `""` you should get it as second index like `Regex.Split(elemList[i].Value, @"\D+")[1]`.
in the other side if there may be number before first `score` you can split the string of element base `Score:` word and `substring` second split-ed index to first `;` like:

```
foreach (var element in currentWorkfileDoc1.Descendants("EventNotes"))
{
    string[] strPart = element.Value.Split(new string[] { "Score:" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    sum += int.Parse(strPart[1].Substring(0, strPart[1].IndexOf(';')));
}
```

note:
Your `xml` document does not have any `root` element which cause a problem to load it in `XmlDocument` I tried second snipped code for your XML and everything works fine

```
<root>
<RepairOrderEvent>
    <EventType>Advisor - Repair Facility</EventType>
    <EventDateTime>2019-01-07T11:18:38.8756279-06:00</EventDateTime>
    <EventNotes>Weld-through primer is not included.; Rule Type: Estimate Line; Score: 1; Variance: 0.0; UniqueSequenceNum: 9</EventNotes>
</RepairOrderEvent> 
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this and give your feedback. Ended up going with the XML document and we do have a root, it was just at the top, where as the XML data given here was just a small snippet.